# I want to reposition a image that is within a div tag without moving the entire div tag

Tags: css, html

I am making a horizontal navigation bar with a image in it, the nav bar has four links in total one of which is a image link, however the image link doesn't line up with the rest of the links on the nav bar i want to drop it down by a pixel or 2, but every time i try and reposition that image it brings the rest of the links in the div tag with it.

{ position: absolute; } and { position: relative; } puts the image link on top of the other links

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KrbT.jpg how it looks normally.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx0Y0.jpg with absolute positioning.

Comment: Please post the code in a snippet (icon on the editor's toolbar that looks like a page with brackets), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skdqcbm0/

Comment: position:relative; top:4px; works fine for me when used on #apps

Comment: sigh it sucks getting stuck on brain dead easy problems, i fiddled with both absolute and relative in the #app section i must have made some kind of other mistake when i first tried relative. anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#apps {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/zryq65d0/1/)

**SNIPPET**

```css
#top-navbar {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13pt;
  position: relative;
}
#signin {
  background-color: #4387FD;
  color: white;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-spacing: 1px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#apps {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Gmail</li>
    <li>Images</li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/options/">
        <img id="apps" src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/ExOY2XlSbdfFFE3BZ5l44wBQEU5JVsVrertIIdjPy93yfDfomhKx0waLXA9Hhv5qvg-b3aaq=w22" />
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="signin" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/webhp%3Fhl%3Den">Sign In</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```